# force scrollbar itself to stop moving upwards (fake limit) while the div is still being scrolled up.

Tags: scrollbar, overlapping

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ezQ9/2/

On my site, I am using NiceScroll3 to have a scrollbar within the container div which is pulling data with AJAX. My problem is this: when I scroll to the top of the container div, the scrollbar itself continues to scroll under the header and to the top of the container. This is normal, I know, but I would like the scrollbar to stop at the bottom of the header when the container finishes scrolling. Basically, I want the scrollbar to stop with a top-margin that this the same as the height of my header (i.e.: not overlap with the header). I have searched endlessly and cannot find a solution online. Thank you in advance!

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">STICKY HEADER</div>
<div id="content">CONTENT
<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT <br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT <br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />CONTENT<br />
</div>
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    height: auto; !important;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
}
#header {   
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#content {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 44px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    max-width: 1105px;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    margin-right: auto;
    background:#252525;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could use a jQuery scroll event and not let pass the height of the header something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2ezQ9/4/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 58) {
        $(this).scrollTop(58);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's closer than I have been able to get, but this also causes the container itself to be locked. The container should scroll to the top as if everything was normal, but it's the scrollbar that should stop at a lower position even though it's really at the height of the page. The container itself should move normally. I fear I will have to rewrite my work and change it to margin-top instead of padding-top :/

Comment: I see, why don't you just make the container scroll instead of the whole page?

Comment: It is the container. It has padding-top equal to height of the header. Essentially, the header is on top of the container. I could change it to margin-top and make padding-top: 0 but that would require repositioning sticky header, toggling nav elements, and so forth. If possible, I would like to avoid this. However, I realize using margin would have been a better option.

Comment: I decided to rewrite my margins/paddings. Now my isotope is acting up with adding a scrollbar plugin, but I can search around for stuff for that knowing I have a more sounds structure now. It was a fool's pursuit. Thanks for your help though.